# Does Tensorflow keep track of train/validation split?

Tags: image, tensorflow, keras

There is a useful utility function in Tensorflow that makes it really simple to load a dataset made of images as a Tensorflow dataset, namely `tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory`.

In the tutorial [at this page here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images), the following operations are performed sequentially in order to obtain a training and a validation dataset:

```
train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)
val_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)
```

My question is: does Tensorflow keep track of which images were placed in the training dataset, in order not to accidentally pick the same images for the validation set? Or could there be duplicates?

Comment: I think it will if there aren't any duplicates in the dataset. Take a look at the docs: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory

Answer (score 0):

The 'validation_split' splits data into 2 classes by order of index. i.e. first 80% data will be in train_ds and remaining 20% data will be in test_ds.

=> Yes, duplicates is possible if you use validation_split value more than 20% in test_ds.